# JS Making a specific word entered into a textbox trigger a password prompt that when correctly entered, you are directed to a new page

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Making a specific word entered into a textbox trigger a password prompt that when correctly entered, you are directed to a new page.

Here is what I have so far. I could be way off the mark, but I would like to make it work somehow. This is just for fun, and really does not help in real life, but someone told me I couldn't do it, so now I'm trying to. Here's what I have.

```
<form id="form1">
<input type="text" id="txtInput" size="1" onblur="checkValue()" />
</form>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
function checkValue()
{
var txtCtrl = document.getElementById("txtInput");

var txtValue = txtCtrl.value;

if (txtValue == "test" || txtValue == "vgx" || txtValue == "vgc" || txtValue == "pcv" || txtValue == "pcg")
{
prompt('Enter Password','');
}
if (password != 'pass','password') 
{ 
window.location.href='http://google.com';
}
}
</script>
```

I'm really sorry I suck so much with JS, kinda new.

Many thanks,
Danny

Comment: I forgot to add, the part I can't get to work, are the multiple if statements, I can get the password prompt to appear, but when I enter the correct password, nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function checkValue()
{
    var txtCtrl = document.getElementById("txtInput");

    var txtValue = txtCtrl.value;

    if (txtValue == "test" || txtValue == "vgx" || txtValue == "vgc" || txtValue == "pcv" || txtValue == "pcg")
    {
        var password = prompt('Enter Password','');

        if (password == 'pass') 
        { 
            window.location.href='http://google.com';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: awesome, thank you so much! How would I go about doing a store/retrieve of my password from a file located outside off of my document directory? Just wondering, as I said, I'm pretty new to this. Looking to learn as much as I can.

Comment: You can read the file using JQuery. Check out the `$.get("file_location", function(data) { })` function.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work because Javascript is visible to the client browser. That is, anyone can just view the source of your page and see your entire script, including the password.

Consider using a database, or at the very least store/retrieve your password from a file located outside of your document directory.

Comment: I am not worried about security, just the principle. Like I said, it's not going to actually be used, just to prove that it can be done

Comment: That's the thing, though -- if this can never be used in practice, what are you trying to prove? You might as well say have a page that says "Type the word 'letmein' to continue."

Comment: I know, my friend and I are trying to grasp at the basics, and this is how we are doing it, giving each other challenges we think are hard, but are super easy to someone who knows what to do. We try and figure it out, just to get experience with the language. If someone wants to explain how to do either of the things you mentioned earlier, I am all ears(or eyes as it were).

Comment: I see... kudos to you and your friend for taking an active approach to learning! As a next exercise, Javascript is not ideal for password authentication. Look into learning PHP -- it's essential knowledge if you're looking to expand your web development skills. If you have experience in PHP, look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php to get started reading a password file!

Comment: many thanks. I will read up on PHP, is doing a store/retrieve of my password from a file located outside off of my document directory a JS or PHP function?

Comment: That, and in fact the whole authentication process, would be done via PHP.